# Add attribute to property to override get /set in entityclass using code-first Entity Framework 6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localization

Because I want to add localization for some string columns in a JSON way for some entities, I was hoping to add an attribute that I can add to the property that can handle this logic.

So i want to save my string in the database to something like:

```
[{'en':'Hello', 'nl':'Hallo', 'fr':'Bonjour'}]
```

Then, when getting this property, I want to add some logic so the right language is returned based on the Current Culture.
I can manage writing this logic, but I'm wondering if it's possible to write something like an Actionfilter (Attribute) Is that possible and how? As you can see I want to globally override the getter as well as the setter for properties decorated with this attribute. The properties are in the entity-classes for EF.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want to save a json instead of some columns?

Comment: because I don't want the change model everytime we're adding a language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localisation, along with aspects such as security, tenancy, etc, are cross-cutting concerns.

Some other ORM's have out-of-the-box support for **filters** that allow entities to have a global filter applied to them at the context level.

This allows all queries within the context to be filtered by some aspect of the cross cutting concern. In your example, the current location.

**There is bolt-on support for filters for Entity Framework** through the EntityFramework.Filters OSS project here: https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters.

This would work *something* like this:

1. Somewhere in the http request pipeline, create the context to service that request and enable your localisation filter on the context. Set the localisation attribute on the filter to be the current culture token.
2. Re-use this context for all database operations within a request. In this way all queries executed against the context will have localisation filters applied to them
3. Your localisation filter would need to be written to append a **where** clause to your Strings lookup entity to filter the entity by the current culture

Some **very rough** example code:

**In your context**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(...)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Strings>().
        Filter("localisation", 
        // setup up your localisation filter
```

**Somewhere in the asp.net mvc pipeline (for example within the authentication filter)**

```
// Create context
var myContext = ..
// Enable the localisation filter using the current cutler
myContext.EnableFilter("localisation").
    SetParameter("culture", "en");
```

Excuse the nature of my example code - I haven't used filters since I set them up for tenancy on our existing project and can't remember the syntax off the top of my head. The GitHub project site has a good worked example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will try this project and come back to you later.. I find it strange it's so hard to find good examples or ways to implement localization with ef
"

Comment: I searched out the original blogpost from the guys that implemented Filters in EF - worth a read if you have the time. They have a few articles around Entity Framework "missing features" (c.f Nhibernate) which are all equally good reads. http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Could come in handy. After a lot of thinking i decided to go with another db design for localization as column sizes could get very big when using many languages in the future. I'll mark your answer though as I could get to the solution as proposed in my question..